# Adding data alongside model.errors.add

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking to send along some data alongside errors.  I am guessing it's somewhere in the responders, though not a clue where to start.  In essence, I want to do

```
model.errors.add :some_attr, "error message"
model.also_send_attrs = { prop: "some data also sent" }
```

and have the structure be the usual (with some appends)

```
{ 
  errors: { some_attr: ['error message'] },
  also_send_data: { prop: "some data also sent" }
}
```

so is it possible to send data alongside an error, if one occurs?

Comment: Could you provide more info about the situation you want to solve this way? Maybe we can find another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm, extending Rails.

```
# config/initializers/also_send_attrs.rb

module AlsoSendAttrs
  module ErrorsExtension
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    included do
      delegate :also_send_attrs, :to => :@base
    end
  end

  module ActiveRecordExtension
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    included do
      attr_accessor :also_send_attrs
    end
  end

  ActiveModel::Errors.send(:include, ErrorsExtension)
  ActiveSupport.on_load :active_record do
    include ActiveRecordExtension
  end
end
```

This is a basic approach.

Each model has an accessor :also_send_attrs and each Errors has an access to this accessor.
For more functionality extend code.